# Why I can't override deactivate order button into lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

I am trying to override the deactivate order button into a lightning component. However, it seems that it doesn't have this option:
[image]

I am a bit confused about this since we are definitely in lightning experience and I can override the new and edit button of order into lightning components.

Is there any reason why I can't do this? And is there a walkaround here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is a limitation with salesforce. You can only override these
>   standard buttons: New, View, Edit, and Delete.

This is why you were able to override for new and edit but not for deactivate. But overriding with VF page is available for almost others standard button.

> As a workaround, You can create quick action having the content source
>   of your Lightning Component and add it to layout and remove the
>   standard button from Layout.

Here are all the limitations:-

1. You can override buttons on the detail page but not the edit page of
   a record.
2. You can only override these standard buttons: New, View, Edit, and
   Delete.
3. You can’t change buttons on lookup dialogs, reports, or tabs.
   However, you can change the buttons on list view and search result
   layouts under search layouts. Action overrides on the New standard
   button don't work on New Object links in lookup searches.
4. You can’t relabel or relocate standard buttons on a record detail
   page. When overriding tabs or buttons with a Lightning component,
   you can select only Lightning components that implement the
   lightning:actionOverride interface.
5. A standard button (New, Edit, View, Delete, and Clone) overridden
   with a Visualforce page doesn’t show up in the Salesforce app unless
   the Visualforce page is enabled for Salesforce mobile apps.
   Overriding standard list and tab controls isn’t supported in mobile.
6. When overriding tabs with a Visualforce page, you can select only
   Visualforce pages that use the standard list controller for that
   tab’s associated object, pages with a custom controller, or pages
   with no controller.
7. When overriding lists with a Visualforce page, you can select only
   Visualforce pages that use a standard list controller.
8. When overriding buttons with a Visualforce page, you can select only
   Visualforce pages that use the standard controller for the object on
   which the button appears. For example, if you want to use a page to
   override the Edit button on accounts, the page markup must include
   the standardController="Account" attribute on the  tag:

Reference:-

1. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=links_override_considerations.htm&type=5
2. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=links_customize_override.htm&type=0